# Visual Studio Code Remote Containers with AWS Cloud Computer source code is missing

Tags: c, docker, visual-studio-code

I am able to debug on a Ubuntu 20.04 machine with Docker containers just fine.

I recently attempted to run the source code and debug it on a AWS instance that I created in the cloud by modifying the two files:

~/.ssh/config

~/.config/Code/User/settings.json

Visual Studio Code connects from my local Ubuntu Linux development machine to now the machine in the AWS cloud.  After all this happens successfully, the project folder that is supposed to container the source code is completely empty.  Please take a look at the attachment:
[image: Visual Studio Code Remote Container Development on AWS Ubuntu Machine]

Why is Visual Studio Code not copying the source code on the target computer in the AWS cloud?  Do I need to add something else to the devcontainer.json file to make it do this?